# I don' t understand (line != null)

Tags: c#, null, line

I've been following C# tutorials and I had a "homework" assignment to read a text file backwards, I managed to accomplish it however I don't understand the, Given Answer, in the tutorial. Here is my solution followed by the one given to me.

#### My solution

```
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("DecodeThis.txt");

string line = myReader.ReadLine();
char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();

Array.Reverse(charArray);
Console.WriteLine(charArray);
Console.ReadLine();
```

#### Given solution

```
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("DecodeThis.txt");
string line = "";

while (line != null)
{
    line = myReader.ReadLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        Console.WriteLine(charArray);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

They both accomplish the same result but I really would like to understand the given solution and how it is different from my own. I assume my solution has disadvantages.

Comment: p.s. I am only 2 weeks new to C# so please be nice :p

Comment: Your solution seems to only read one line from the file, while the given solution reads all lines.

Comment: Yours will read only one line while the other solution will read lines until there are none left to read. The fact that they both yield the same result probably means you are reading a file with only one line in it.

Comment: [Consult the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), *especially* when the method in question is known: "The next line from the input stream, *or null* if the end of the input stream is reached."

Comment: Thanks everyone :) I also understand != null means is not empty now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads each line of the file, one at a time. This is useful in case the file is huge and you would run out of memory attempting to store it in a string.

Once the last line has been read, the next call of `ReadLine()` will return null.

I'm guessing this wasn't a problem for you as the file was only 1 line long.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

You're doing very well for 2 weeks in. Keep going!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that your solution only reads and returns the first line. The solution given reads and reverses every line in the file.

The reason why you check line for null is because once you're out of text in the file, `ReadLine()` will return null, so it stops the loop from being infinite.

Answer (score 0):

your solution just reads a single line whereas the book solution reads the file, line by line until there is no more lines to read. :)
This is because it is using a while loop to check to see if there is anymore data/lines read. if not, it will be null. However a better proposed solution would be to check the EndOfStream flag instead

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example reads only one line, given solution reads entire file line by line. Checking null is important because myReader.ReadLine() returns null, if there's no more lines to read.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

Answer (score 0):

taking a quick look your solution only reads one line.
The given solution keeps reading lines until it reads a line that equals null. This happens at the end of the file. (if you would keep reading after that you'd get an exception)

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine reads a file line by line. So your solution only reads the first line of the file. However, if the requirement is to read all lines of the file, you need to loop over the lines as the given solution does.
Checking the return value of ReadLine against null is important in order to recognize that the end of the file has been reached. If ReadLine returns null (instead of an empty string), the end has been reached and the loop can be stopped.
See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of ReadLine for detailed information on how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same result because, probably, your file have only one row!

The "given solution" instead, iterate (read and reverse) **all** file's rows, while your solution is valid for just one row.